# import @material js library via CDN

Tags: javascript, typescript, umd

I'm trying to import material design into my project using import maps.

But I have run into problems. I'm trying to import it via importmap, but since all material components are inside @material/[component] namespaces, but the CDN from Material design documenation proxyes to a module (UMD if i remember corectly) which is a single file which contains all those namespaces as exports.

For example:

```
import { MDCList } from '@material/list';
const l = new MDCList(...);
```

Is Equivalent to:

```
import { list } from 'material-design-web';
const l = new list.MDCList(...);
```

But there is no CDN for @material as far as I know, so is there is a way, to tell it to treat the content after the slash like a namespace inside the module?

somethink like this:

```
<script type="importmap">
{
   "imports": {
       "@@material/": "https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"
    }
}
</script>
```

but this throws an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@material/list". Import Map: "@material/list" matches with "@material/" but is blocked by a null value`

is there a way around this? Or do I have to just forget about using CDN? (Whitout changing the inputs)

Comment: This seems to be the only other ref to this on the internet :') . Also have the same issue trying to use import-maps for a custom local module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the CDN version, it looks like there are [no paths](https://unpkg.com/browse/material-components-web@14.0.0/dist/) for it follow.

Instead all of the modules underneath paths have been web-packed into the root module, so for your particular module import you'd do this:

Import map

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
   "imports": {
       "@material/": "https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"
    }
}
</script>
```

Then later

```js
import { list as MDCList } from "@material"
```

---

As an aside, I ran into the same error `Failed to resolve module specifier ... but is blocked by a null value` with a slightly different circumstance. In my case it was that I didn't add a trailing slash to the right hand side of my import map entry.

EX: had this:
`"tools/" : "./tools"`
But instead needed this : `"tools/" : "./tools/"` **note the additional slash**.

---

For your case in particular you'd need either a local path or remote CDN that served the non-webpacked module file tree. Then you'd be able to do something like:

```json
"imports": {
       "@material/": "https://fake-magic-cdn.com/material-components/"
    }
```

...

```
import { MDCList } from '@material/list';
```

However, since your CDN serves a web-packed version, instead use the setup provided in first part of answer.

Answer (score 0):

i had same error but for me, i've imported via npm and the libraries should be referenced by path to node_modules
for ex: "@pixiv/three-vrm": "./node_modules/@pixiv/three-vrm/lib/three-vrm.module.js"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).